# When to use Collections vs when to add extra function to a concrete subclass of a list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Consider the following code to detect if linkedlist has a loop

```
 public boolean hasLoop() {

    Node<E> fast = first;
    Node<E> slow = first;

    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {

        fast = fast.next.next;

        slow = slow.next;

        if (slow == fast) {

            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

If `Sun Microsystems` were to add functionalities (like: `detectLoop, reverseLinkedlist, findIf2linkedlist intersect` etc) into `Linkedlist.java`, how would they do it ?
Note, Sun uses Node class as an internal detail (ie private).

A few options that I can think of ( listed with disadvantages of each)

1. Static function 'hasLoop' in Linkedlist.java ? ( this is weird, because if I want to do hasLoop for existing `instance`, I would call it `LinkedList.mergeSort(instance)` rather than `instance.mergeSort()` )
2. Non-static function 'hasLoop' in Linkedlist.java? ( this would be weird because some functions like `sort` belong to collections )
3. Subclass an Linkedlist.java and add new function 'hasLoop' ? ( this would be weird because if I need to add another function like say `findIntersection`, I would need to create another subclass )
4. Somehow use Collections and add a static method 'hasLoop(List)', and add additional interfaces into LinkedList.java to make it somehow possible ?  ( it would be ugly as Node is private class with internal implementation, and `ptr.next` cannot be performed by collections. It would need some setters to modify state like `setNext()` etc.)

Comment: hasLoop what is it? returns true if `list.size > 1`?

Answer (score 0):

A loop makes sense only in case of a linked list among all lists. So, such functionality should be specific to a `LinkedList`. The simplest way would be :

- Add an instance method to LinkedList implementation: `hasLoop()`

*OR*

- Make LinkedList implement `Loopable<E>` where

  > ```
  > Loopable<E>{
  >    boolean hasLoop();
  > }
  > ```

Comment: and generics is for something special?

Comment: kept it there for extension for something like `E getLoopNode()`. It  can be omitted in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited my question to make it more generic - ( functions would be like: detectLoop, reverseLinkedlist, findIf2linkedlist intersect etc). Do u still recommend the same ?

Comment: All the APIs you mention are LinkedList specific, so yes I would still take the same route. All it boils to is the design.